# What numpy structures are expected as inputs to use numpy.char functions?

Tags: python, string, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Consider a numpy array of array of strings (at least my closest take on how to do that):

```
ff = np.array([['a:bc','d:ef'],['g:hi','j:kl']])
print(ff.dtype)
<U4
```

But these can not be used with the `numpy.char` methods apparently .. ?

```
ffc = ff.astype('S5')
fff = np.char.split(ffc,':')[1]


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/defchararray.py", line 1447, in split
    a, object_, 'split', [sep] + _clean_args(maxsplit))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'numpy.str_'
```

What is the difference between type `<U4` and `.str_` and how can the strings shown be parsed by `np.char.**` ?

Comment: If the dtype is `U` use unicode parameters. If a  bytestring dtype `S` use a bytestring parameter, `b':'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `np.char` functions are meant to work on `chararrays`, which should be constructed with `np.char.array` or `np.char.asarray` (see the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html#numpy-chararray)).

Accordingly, your given code would work like this:

```
ff = np.array([['a:bc','d:ef'],['g:hi','j:kl']])
ffc = np.char.asarray(ff)
fff = np.char.split(ffc, ':')[1]

print(fff)
```

Output:

```
[list(['g', 'hi']) list(['j', 'kl'])]
```

This conversion is implicitly performed, so this, in fact, would also work:

```
ff = np.array([['a:bc','d:ef'],['g:hi','j:kl']])
fff = np.char.split(ff, ':')[1]
```

For completeness, your subsidiary question about `<U4` vs `S5`:

A `numpy` `dtype` with `U` signifies a unicode string, which is the [recommended way of representing strings](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types). On the other hand, `S` represents a null-terminated byte array.

My suspicion is that the string methods are performed upon Python objects, and therefore you need a Python string-like type (knows its own length, etc.) rather than a "dumb" C string-like byte array.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I had _started_ with using the `np.array` directly (without invoking the `astype('S5')` and had received the same error as shown in the OP.  But the code (as shown in your third snippet) does work.

Comment: @javadba Could be a `numpy` version issue, or a stale variable. Would you happen to have been working in a Jupyter notebook or equivalent?

Comment: No i'm using `pycharm`

Comment: See the note in `np.char` about the current use of `np.chararrays`.

Answer (score 1):

The string type in the parameter must match the type in the array:

```
In [44]: ff = np.array([['a:bc','d:ef'],['g:hi','j:kl']])                            
In [45]: ff                                                                          
Out[45]: 
array([['a:bc', 'd:ef'],
       ['g:hi', 'j:kl']], dtype='<U4')
In [46]: np.char.split(ff,':')                                                       
Out[46]: 
array([[list(['a', 'bc']), list(['d', 'ef'])],
       [list(['g', 'hi']), list(['j', 'kl'])]], dtype=object)
In [47]: np.char.split(ff.astype('S5'),b':')                                         
Out[47]: 
array([[list([b'a', b'bc']), list([b'd', b'ef'])],
       [list([b'g', b'hi']), list([b'j', b'kl'])]], dtype=object)
```

'U4' is unicode, the default string type for Py3.  'S4' is bytestring, the default type for Py2.  `b':'` is a bytestring, `u':'` is unicode.

This `np.char.split` is a bit awkward to use, since the result is object dtype, with lists of the split strings.

To get 2 separate arrays I'd use `frompyfunc` to apply an unpacking:

```
In [50]: np.frompyfunc(lambda alist: tuple(alist), 1,2)(_46)                         
Out[50]: 
(array([['a', 'd'],
        ['g', 'j']], dtype=object), array([['bc', 'ef'],
        ['hi', 'kl']], dtype=object))
In [51]: np.frompyfunc(lambda alist: tuple(alist), 1,2)(_47)                         
Out[51]: 
(array([[b'a', b'd'],
        [b'g', b'j']], dtype=object), array([[b'bc', b'ef'],
        [b'hi', b'kl']], dtype=object))
```

though to get string dtype arrays I'd still have use `astype`:

```
In [52]: _50[0].astype('U4')                                                         
Out[52]: 
array([['a', 'd'],
       ['g', 'j']], dtype='<U4')
```

I could combine the unpacking and astype with `np.vectorize` by providing `otypes` (even a mix of dtypes!):

```
In [53]: np.vectorize(lambda alist:tuple(alist), otypes=['U4','S4'])(_46)            
Out[53]: 
(array([['a', 'd'],
        ['g', 'j']], dtype='<U1'), array([[b'bc', b'ef'],
        [b'hi', b'kl']], dtype='|S2'))
```

Usually `frompyfunc` is faster than `vectorize`.

This unpacking won't work if the split creates different length lists:

```
In [54]: ff = np.array([['a:bc','d:ef'],['g:hi','j:kl:xyz']])                        
In [55]: np.char.split(ff,':')                                                       
Out[55]: 
array([[list(['a', 'bc']), list(['d', 'ef'])],
       [list(['g', 'hi']), list(['j', 'kl', 'xyz'])]], dtype=object)
```

===

With a `chararray`, all these `np.char` functions are available as methods.

```
In [59]: np.char.asarray(ff)                                                         
Out[59]: 
chararray([['a:bc', 'd:ef'],
           ['g:hi', 'j:kl:xyz']], dtype='<U8')
In [60]: np.char.asarray(ff).split(':')                                              
Out[60]: 
array([[list(['a', 'bc']), list(['d', 'ef'])],
       [list(['g', 'hi']), list(['j', 'kl', 'xyz'])]], dtype=object)
```

See the note in the `np.char` docs:

> The `chararray` class exists for backwards compatibility with
>      Numarray, it is not recommended for new development. Starting from numpy
>      1.4, if one needs arrays of strings, it is recommended to use arrays of
>      `dtype` `object_`, `string_` or `unicode_`, and use the free functions
>      in the `numpy.char` module for fast vectorized string operations.

Comment: Heavy duty treatise. I'll come back to this when not under the gun to properly absorb